# How do I delete programs that dont exist according to windows explorer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, file-corruption

Windows 10, I force closed steam while it was writing to the hard disk and now all the games i had in the steamapp/common on my C:/ drive are gone.

BUT

Steam is still downloading synced data from the cloud for these games, but to install them i need to free up space

BUT i cant free up space because Windows Explorer doesn't see them...

BUT Recuva finds them.

BUT it ignores them regardless of filter settings....

SO now, i have only a few megabytes of free space on my c drive and i need to someone clear up 200 gigabytes of data that i cant clear up because the files dont exist.

I'm assuming I'm royally donefor and I'm ready to just give up. I was planning on getting an ssd anyways.

TLDR:
 - force closed steam while it was writing to disk

- steam/common folder is "empty"
- file space is still occupied by programs that "dont exist"
- recuva ignores the files
- cant free up enough space to have steam check for installed games
- need to delete files that "dont exist"
- steam client cant send support ticket for whatever reason

Turns out steam moved the steamapps folder into the steamui folder. steam is weird. Hello future people trying to fix this! check to see if some other steam directory folders are a bit too big...

Comment: Programs can be uninstalled in the add and remove programs icon in control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let Recuva try to recover anything. Recuva isn't intended for this and may make matters worse!

First reboot your computer. Chances are that Windows will insist on doing a "Check Disk" action on reboot. Let it do that.
If Windows doesn't do it by itself you will have to force it. Open a Command Prompt or PowerShell Prompt as "Administrator" and issue the command "chkdsk c: /F". It will probably tell you it can't do that straight away but only on reboot, so give another reboot.

After chkdsk is done your problem is most likely fixed.
ChkDsk should either really remove that allocated data, or turn the missing data back into normal files (either in the original location or recovers them to files called file?????.chk in the root of C:). You should be able to delete those files normally.

Comment: I've told chkdsk to do the thing on the next restart, thank you. will update.

Comment: Turns out steam moved the steamapps folder into the steamui folder. steam is weird.

Comment: I will reiterate that Recuva should absolutely never be used for any reason.